# iOS click html button

Tags: html, ios, button, click

I have an html-page with button on it:

```
<input type='button' onClick='btnReset()' value='Save/Reboot'>
```

This page have basic authentication.
I have to perform click on this button.

In C# I have method to emulate click:

```
WebBrowser.Document.All(input).InvokeMember("click")
```

But I don't know how to do this action in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your input the following method:

```
checked="true"
```